# Can I use Javascript do detect whether a user is on another open tab, rather than my website?

Tags: javascript, browser

I want to know if a user is currently active on another opened browser tab, and not currently interacting on my website. This way I could use Javascript to write novel HTML into the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibility API - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)

Example from MDN

```js
// Set the name of the hidden property and the change event for visibility
var hidden, visibilityChange;
if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support
  hidden = "hidden";
  visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "msHidden";
  visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
} else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
  hidden = "webkitHidden";
  visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
}

var videoElement = document.getElementById("videoElement");

// If the page is hidden, pause the video;
// if the page is shown, play the video
function handleVisibilityChange() {
  if (document[hidden]) {
    videoElement.pause();
  } else {
    videoElement.play();
  }
}

// Warn if the browser doesn't support addEventListener or the Page Visibility API
if (typeof document.addEventListener === "undefined" || hidden === undefined) {
  console.log("This demo requires a browser, such as Google Chrome or Firefox, that supports the Page Visibility API.");
} else {
  // Handle page visibility change
  document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, handleVisibilityChange, false);

  // When the video pauses, set the title.
  // This shows the paused
  videoElement.addEventListener("pause", function(){
    document.title = 'Paused';
  }, false);

  // When the video plays, set the title.
  videoElement.addEventListener("play", function(){
    document.title = 'Playing';
  }, false);
}
```